# How can I retrieve field in Propel?

Tags: symfony-1.4, propel

I need to get the whole field 'username' from my DB.

Can I do it with model class or Peer-class?

There are many ways to solve that using Query-class, but command `propel:build-model` didn't create Query-classes. I don't understand why.

Comment: Which version of propel are you using? Can you add your schema.yml?

Comment: Problem is solved. I use $users = wiEdmsUserPeer::doSelect(new Criteria()) to get all elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved. I use

```
$users = wiEdmsUserPeer::doSelect(new Criteria())
```

to get all elements.

Another way is:

```
$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->addSelectColumn($column_name);
wiEdmsUserPeer::doSelect($criteria);
```

Answer (score 0):

Query classes weren't generated because you probably aren't using the latest version of Propel. Using Query classes is cleaner and works better than criteria, consider upgrading!